# Wileyfox Swift Mobile data not working after update to Nougat 7.1.1

Tags: mobile-data, 7.1-nougat

I recently applied the Android Nougat 7.1.1 update to my partner's Wileyfox Swift.  This update replaced Cyanogen with a more stock install.  Since the update, mobile data no longer works.  Symptoms:

- In the status menu, it says "Emergency Calls Only", but the phone can in fact make calls and send texts as normal.
- In Systems > SIM cards, it shows the SIM card for Three UK ('3') installed in slot 1.

  - Under "Preferred SIM for", it says "**Mobile data: Selection required**", but *this item is greyed out so no selection can be made*.  (For Calls and SMS messages, it correctly shows that the '3' SIM is selected.
- In Settings > Data usage, under '3' it shows that mobile data is enabled.
- In Settings > Mobile network settings > APNs, it shows the '3 UK' APN selected.  APN details are as specified on the three.co.uk website.
- In Settings > About phone > Status > SIM Status, it shows the network (3), Signal strength (-73 dBm 20 asu), Mobile network type (HSPA), Service status (In service), Mobile network status (**disconnected**) and My phone number (**Unknown**).

I have tried rebooting, as well as booting without sim then rebooting with.

What could be preventing mobile data from working after an update to 7.1.1?

Answer (score 1):

Overall it looks like a issue related to the kernel. I would say it would be possible to fix this just by installing another version and/or install a custom kernel which very likely fix this issue if it is related to the kernel. While you are trying this I would also recommend contacting the developer and reporting this issue. Also try another Simcard slot if you can. I had a similar issue sometimes with my phone too but a reboot fixed the issue usually.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to make it work, buy following the instructions below:

1. Wiped the cache  (not sure if this is related or not, but I did it)
2. Removed All APNs, disable mobile data, Reboot the phone
3. Create a new APN and set "Bearer type" of the APN to "GPRS,LTE,EDGE" and un-checked the first item "unspecified", and save the APN.

   4. Reboot the phone, Enable mobile data.